# How can function arguments, be put in some sort of protected environment, without pcall nesting?

Tags: logging, error-handling, lua, environment

I've made an example code here, to explain my question better.

```lua
local t = {}

function printTest(...)
    print(...)
end
```

The issue I want to solve is to catch an error, when calling this function `printTest()` with any error causing arguments, as example: `printTest(t.example.example)`. But without having to nest `printTest()` itself inside a `pcall()`.

What I was mainly trying to do with this code, is that I wanted to make some sort of new console output, that will log things, whenever `printTest()` gets called, without touching the persisting console environment.

However the issue were that errors would still end up to the main console.

So I tried, doing this because I wanted to see if I could somehow have a `pcall_function`

```lua
otherTest = function(...)
    local status, response = pcall(test, ...)

    if (status == false) then
        print(response)
    end
end
```

However, calling `otherTest.(t.example.example)` gives the error

`attempt to index a nil value (field 'example')`

just like how `printTest(t.example.example)` would.

A way to solve this issue would be by nesting the function inside a pcall, like so

```lua
local status, response = pcall(function() printTest(t.example.example) end)

if (status == false) then
    printTest(response)
end
```

However, I am trying to make a function that is independent from having to be nested inside a pcall like that, or anything, that would let me call `printTest(t.example.example)` and catching the error. And so therefore I am looking for alternative solutions.

I want to implement this pcall check inside the function `printTest()`, but I am not sure if there's a way to do that.

I was thinking about something like `printTest(protected_check(t.example.example))` or something that calls when `printTest()` has been tried to be called with something that would error, but I don't think it exists.

Comment: `I want to implement this pcall check inside the function printTest()` - It is impossible because the error is generated while arguments are being calculated before invoking the function.

Answer (score 1):

The 'test' in the pcall() could be: assert
Because assert can also used to have a default.
Look: https://www.lua.org/manual/5.4/manual.html#pdf-assert
Example

```
 local notexistent = false or nil
 local b, r = pcall(assert, notexistent, "Sorry - Thats not working")
 print(r)
-- Output: Sorry - Thats not working
```

As a default...
The `assert()` returning a string message (or number) if fail.
That message could be also a function as a string.
An `assert()` text message function could be converted to a function with: `load()`
And with `load()` you can give a function an own environment...

```
local notexistent = false or nil
local b, r = pcall(assert,
notexistent,
[[return function(msg) print(msg) end]])

if not b then
 r = load(r, 'assert_func_msg', 't', {print = io.write})()
 r('[' .. debug.getinfo(r).source .. ']\tSorry - This is not working\n')
end
-- Output: [assert_func_msg]    Sorry - This is not working
```

Look: https://www.lua.org/manual/5.4/manual.html#pdf-load